# Run my web application in Kiosk mode

Tags: angular, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I am currently doing an online test application for my study.  And I don't want the users to browse to other application (browser) while they are taking the online test.  Is it possible to do?

Currently, I am building my app in Angular2.

Comment: You cannot do that from within your page only (otherwise every other site would exploit it)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: That would be something for the browser or OS to deal with, not a web application

Comment: I mean exactly that - you cannot limit (from your website) what a user does on their computer.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/ check this link

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Raspberry Pi (or any Linux-based system), you can open the Chromium browser in Kiosk Mode.

```
chromium-browser --kiosk https://webpage.example.com
```

You can use this each time you want to start Kiosk mode, or add it to your `~/.bashrc` to open automatically on login.